# Use of @Binds with @Named in Dagger 2

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger

I have my module as shown below,

```
@Module
public abstract class BindsModuleEx {

    @Binds
    @Named("obj2")
    public abstract SomeInterface provideSomeInterface2(SomeInterfaceImpl2 someInterfaceImpl);

    @Binds
    @Named("obj1")
    public abstract SomeInterface provideSomeInterface1(SomeInterfaceImpl1 someInterfaceImpl);
}
```

---

My implementations of `SomeInterface` as shown below

```
public class SomeInterfaceImpl1 implements SomeInterface {
  @Inject
  @Named("obj1")
  public SomeInterfaceImpl1() {
  }
```

---

```
public class SomeInterfaceImpl2 implements SomeInterface {

  @Inject
  @Named("obj2")
  public SomeInterfaceImpl2() {
  }
```

Can I use `@Named` or `@Qualifier` on `@Binds` methods ?
I am aware of using `@Provides` with `@Named` but I would like to know why this doesn't work and whats the right way to solve this kind of situation.

The error message reads like this

```
error: @Qualifier annotations are not allowed on @Inject constructors.
```

~Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The @Named qualifier doesn't go on the constructor declaration - you need to use it on your injection target, e.g. if you were injecting "obj1" in an Activity that's where you would use the qualifier.

Answer (score -1):

This is how I modified it, and it works.

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {

    @Inject
    @Named("obj1")
    SomeInterface someInterface1;

    @Inject
    @Named("obj2")
    SomeInterface someInterface2;
}
```

This is how my Implementations of `SomeInterface` is now

```
public class SomeInterfaceImpl1 implements SomeInterface {
  @Inject
  public SomeInterfaceImpl1() {
  }
```